# C++ program crashes after assign value to a 2D array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, class, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to make a chess game and I'm just begining to learn c++.I have a basedice class and I derived my dice from it. the program crashes after I want to access one of my pieces in gamepos array.In mousepressevent function in knight.cpp the crash happen.Sorry about my english too.

My code is:

basedice.h

```
 class basedice:public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    basedice();
    enum KIND {Kinght,Rook,Pawn,Bishop,Queen,King};
    KIND kind;
    enum COLOR {white,black};
    COLOR color;

    void setposition();

    basedice *gamepos[8][8];

};
```

basedice.cpp

```
basedice::basedice()
{
}

void basedice::setposition()
{
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
         for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
          {
            gamepos[i][j]=NULL;
          }
    }
}
```

board.h

```
class board:public basedice
{
public:
    board();
    void additem(QGraphicsScene *basescene);
    board *_board;

};
```

board.cpp

```
    board::board()
    {
    setZValue(0);
    }

    void board::additem(QGraphicsScene *basescene)
    {
     setposition();
    _board= new board;
    QPixmap boarditem (":/images/board.png");
    _board->setPixmap(boarditem);
    _board->setPos(0,0);

    basescene->addItem(_board);
    }
```

knight.h

```
class knight:public basedice
{
public:
    knight();
    void additem(QGraphicsScene *basescene);
    QVector <knight *>_blackknight;
    QVector <knight *> _whiteknight;
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

}
```

knight.cpp

```
knight::knight()
{
setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
setZValue(1);
}

void knight::additem(QGraphicsScene *basescene)
{

    _blackknight.resize(2);
    _whiteknight.resize(2);
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        _blackknight[i]=new knight;       
        _whiteknight[i]=new knight;
    }

   QPixmap bknight(":/images/basb.png");
   for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {

       _blackknight[i]->setPixmap( bknight);
       _blackknight[i]->setPos(140+i*5*140,0);
       _blackknight[i]->color=black;
       _blackknight[i]->kind=Kinght;
        gamepos[1+i*5][0]=(_blackknight[i]);


       basescene->addItem(_blackknight[i]);

    }

  QPixmap wknight(":/images/wasb.png");
  for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {

      _whiteknight[i]->setPixmap(wknight);
      _whiteknight[i]->setPos(140+i*5*140,980);
      _whiteknight[i]->color=white;

      _whiteknight[i]->kind=Kinght;
      gamepos[1+i*5][7]=(_whiteknight[i]);
      basescene->addItem(_whiteknight[i]);

  }


}


void knight::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
        qDebug()<<gamepos[i][j];//this cause the program to crash
        }
    }
}
```

And the chessscene just for show how I call them:
chessscene.h

```
class chessscene
{
public:
    chessscene();
    QGraphicsScene *basescene;

};
```

chessscene.cpp

```
chessscene::chessscene()
{
  basescene=new QGraphicsScene;

  board _board;
  knight _knight;

  _board.additem(basescene);
  _knight.additem(basescene);
```

}

Comment: Which line does it crash at, exactly?

Comment: In knight.cpp.. in mousepressevent function `qDebug()<<gamepos[i][j]`

Comment: my debugger said It's from pointer's inside it.

Comment: How can I exactly tell my problem better?

Comment: Generally, questions to Stack Overflow aren't designed to be a "help me with this code" sort of thing, they're designed to be "I have a specific phenomena to discuss" sort of thing. Think of Stack Overflow as being a wiki, where the topics to add to the wiki are based on question submissions. The questions are intended to be useful for future readers, who come here searching for answers to their problems; questions about one's own code are only useful the one time to one person. That being said, if I can figure out the answer within a couple of minutes, I still try to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused about who owns what variables in your program. Your problem is that you're not doing what you think you're doing with `basedice *gamepos[8][8];` in your basedice class.

What you are doing is creating a 8x8 matrix of pointers to `bacedice`s *for every class that inherits from `basedice`*. `_board` has its own matrix. Each knight has its own matrix: every item in `_blackknight` and `_whiteknight` vectors have their own separate matrix.

You initialize this matrix with `setposition()`, but you only call that on your `board` class. Later, when you try to debug the `gamepos` for one of your `knight` instances, its `gamepos` matrix hasn't been initialized. These matrices are not shared simply because inheritors all inherit from the same class, rather, they are independent for every instance.

In other words, don't put a `gamepos` matrix in `basedice`. Instead, I would, as one alternative, put it in your `board` class alone, and pass your `board` instance as a pointer to your `knight` if they need access to data that `board` owns. Preferably, you'd create methods on `board` that would encapsulate the `gamepos` variable within your `board` instance, so that, for example, a knight can ask the board where it is situated, and never has to know the existence of `gamepos` at all.

Finally, it seems to me that you shouldn't be inheriting `board` from `basedice` at all, but perhaps directly from `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. Inheritance implies that everything that is true in the parent class is true in the inheriting class. You're saying, in effect, that every board has a KIND, a COLOR, and a matrix of positions, and every piece has a KIND, a COLOR, and a matrix of positions. The KIND and COLOR make no sense for a `board`, and the matrix of positions make little sense in your pieces.